# I'm creating an average retention curve for a business. However, the way I've written it

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm creating an average retention curve for a business. However right now, the denominator in every month is accounting for every customer that had a transaction in month 0 but the problem is after Month 0 not every customer has been a customer long enough to have a transaction in the subsequent months. How would I change this query so the denominator only accounts for customers to have been around long enough to have a transaction in that month? So for instance all customers that had their first transaction in July are removed from Month 1- Month 29 denominator?

Below is the query I'm currently using:

```
SELECT
cohorts.user_count
,CAST(cohorts.user_count AS DECIMAL(36,4)) / first_cohort.user_count AS retention_pct
,cohorts.transaction_count
,cohorts.Cohort
from
(
  select
  count(distinct t.owner) AS user_count
  ,count(t.id) AS transaction_count
  ,datediff(month,[f.first_transaction_date:month],[t.createdon:month]) as Cohort

  from [transaction_cache as t]
  
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT
    owner
    ,MIN(createdon) AS first_transaction_date
    FROM [transaction_cache]
    WHERE [createdon:year] > ['2017-01-01':date:year]
    GROUP BY 1
  ) AS f
  ON f.owner = t.owner

  where [t.createdon:year] > ['2017-01-01':date:year]
  and t.status = 'successful'
  and t.type = 'savings'

  group by 3
) AS cohorts

JOIN
(
  select
  count(distinct t.owner) AS user_count
  ,count(t.id) AS transaction_count
  ,datediff(month,[f.first_transaction_date:month],[t.createdon:month]) as Cohort

  from [transaction_cache as t]
  
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT
    owner
    ,MIN(createdon) AS first_transaction_date
    FROM [transaction_cache]
    WHERE [createdon:year] > ['2017-01-01':date:year]
    GROUP BY 1
  ) AS f
  ON f.owner = t.owner

  where [t.createdon:year] > ['2017-01-01':date:year]
  and t.status = 'successful'
  and t.type = 'savings'
  and datediff(month,[f.first_transaction_date:month],[t.createdon:month]) = 0

  group by 3
) AS first_cohort
ON 1=1
```

order by 4 asc

Comment: Add the schema and sample data with desired output. it will help to answer the question

Comment: The SQL in your question is not valid for Postgres, so you can't be using that. Please add the correct tag for the database system you are using